# How to give same instance of ViewModel to both the Parent and Child fragment

Tags: android, mvvm, dependency-injection, dagger, android-viewmodel

There are two Fragments: ParentFragment and ChildFragment.
`ChildFragment` has been added to a view of the `ParentFragment`.

Now using `Dagger2` for Android has the `ParentFragmentModule` with a method:

```
@Provides
fun provideViewModel(fragment: ParentFragment, myViewModelFactory: MyViewModelFactory): MyViewModel {
    return ViewModelProviders.of(fragment, myViewModelFactory).get(MyViewModelImpl::class.java)
}
```

Where MyViewModelFactory, MyViewModel, MyViewModelImpl are simple ViewModel logic created in the app.

And the ChildFragmentModule has the method:

```
@Provides
fun provideViewModel(fragment: ChildFragment, myViewModelFactory: MyViewModelFactory): MyViewModel {
    return ViewModelProviders.of(fragment, myViewModelFactory).get(MyViewModelImpl::class.java)
}
```

This obviously is creating two separate instances of the `ViewModel` as they receive two different fragment instances.

How do we make it return the same instance so that the data can be shared between both the Parent and Child fragments?

I have tried passing the `ParentFragment` instead of `ChildFragment` in the `ChildFragmentModule`, but that leads to Dagger dependancy injection error.

Comment: see https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel#sharing

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Create your `ViewModel` with `Activity` scope. Then all `Fragment` within that `Activity` will get same `ViewModel` instance.

Check official [ViewModelProviders](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/ViewModelProviders) reference. You can create `ViewModel` with both `Activity` and `Fragment` scope.

```
ViewModelProvider of (FragmentActivity activity)
```

> Creates a ViewModelProvider, which retains ViewModels while a scope of given Activity is alive. More detailed explanation is in ViewModel.

and

```
ViewModelProvider of (Fragment fragment)
```

> Creates a ViewModelProvider, which retains ViewModels while a scope of given fragment is alive. More detailed explanation is in ViewModel.

Sample code for creating `ViewModel`

**From Activity:**

```
 movieListViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MovieListViewModel.class);
```

**From Fragment:**

```
 movieListViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(getActivity()).get(MovieListViewModel.class);
```

Comment: Thank you. This works smooth!
Just for the knowledge, the Parent and Child fragment scopes are alive at the same time. How can achieve the same thing without using the Activity?

Comment: How to share movieListViewModel to different module? Is that possible

Comment: What about single activity approach? It won't be good to hold all the shared view models linked to one activity.

Comment: just a modification to avoid NullPointerException
 movieListViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(requireActivity()).get(MovieListViewModel.class);

Comment: To add on this is it possible to get the view model for a separate activity to send data to the child fragment of the MainActivity?

Answer (score 20):

Using [Fragment-ktx](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/ktx) we can do as `In **ParentFragment**`

```
 private val viewModel: DemoViewModel by viewModels()
```

And

`In ChildFragment`

```
 private val viewModel: DemoViewModel by viewModels(
    ownerProducer = { requireParentFragment() }
)
```

Doing this we can get same instance of **ViewModel** in **Parent Fragment** and **ChildFragment**

add dependencies in **app -> build.gralde**

```
implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.1.0
```

Answer (score 3):

Implement *fragment-ktx* in your *app -> build.gradle*:

```
implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.2.5
```

*If you are using Navigation Component* (https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation)

In the parentFragment, you can get the viewModel like this:

```
private val viewModel by viewModels<DemoViewModel>()
```

And then when you need that viewModel in the childFragment you can get it this way:

```
private val viewModel by viewModels<DemoViewModel>({requireGrandParentFragment()})
```

the *requireGrandParentFragment()* is a custom extension of Fragment:

```
fun Fragment.requireGrandParentFragment() = this.requireParentFragment().requireParentFragment()
```

*If you are not using Navigation Component*

you can access it like this:

```
private val viewModel by viewModels<DemoViewModel>({requireParentFragment()})
```

Answer (score 2):

I have got a same problem tried above all solution but not working in my scenario come up with a other solution using requireParentFragment() return NavHostFragment in child fragment solve it by using

```
private val viewModel: childViewModel by viewModels(
            ownerProducer = { requireParentFragment().childFragmentManager.primaryNavigationFragment!! }
    )
```

in Parent Fragmet use this

```
private val viewModel: MyOrdersVM by viewModels()
```

Answer (score 0):

`ViewModelProvider` constructor has `owner` paramter

```
ViewModelProvider(
    ViewModelStoreOwner owner,
    ViewModelProvider.Factory factory
)
```

Reference on the [official docs.](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/ViewModelProvider#ViewModelProvider(androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelStoreOwner))

This parameters is responsible for scope where `ViewModel` instance would be remain the same. You need to pass the same reference on `ViewModelStoreOwner` to have the same instance of `ViewModel`

In case of sharing `ViewModel` among two fragments that depends on each other as parent - child, you need to get `ViewModel` instance like this:

At parent fragment:

```
viewModel = ViewModelProvider(
  this, 
  viewModelFactory
).get(ProfileViewModel::class.java)
```

At child fragment:

```
viewModel = ViewModelProvider(
  requireParentFragment(), 
  viewModelFactory
).get(ProfileViewModel::class.java)
```

[This resource](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/kotlin-android-training-view-model#4) might be helpful to learn more.